# Same error for all imports: module 'collections' has no attribute 'namedtuple'

Tags: python, python-3.x

Python refuses to import any module, including something as basic as numpy, and throws the same error for all of them.

I am working with Python 3.5.2 and Anaconda 4.2.0 (64-bit) with GCC 4.4.7 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1). I recently installed the following modules via pip:

- packaging
- appdirs
- triangle
- glumpy

See example feedback below.

```
>>> import numpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
  from . import add_newdocs
File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
  from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/lib/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
  from .type_check import *
File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/lib/type_check.py", line 11, in <module>
  import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 33, in <module>
  from . import _internal  # for freeze programs
File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/core/_internal.py", line 12, in <module>
  from numpy.compat import asbytes, basestring
File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/compat/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
  from . import _inspect
File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/compat/_inspect.py", line 10, in <module>
  import types
File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/types.py", line 166, in <module>
  import functools as _functools
File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/functools.py", line 21, in <module>
  from collections import namedtuple
File "/anaconda3/pkgs/vispy-0.4.0.106.gf8a69d0-np110py35_0/lib/python3.5/site-packages/vispy/visuals/collections/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
  from . path_collection import PathCollection  # noqa
File "/anaconda3/pkgs/vispy-0.4.0.106.gf8a69d0-np110py35_0/lib/python3.5/site-packages/vispy/visuals/collections/path_collection.py", line 6, in <module>
  from . raw_path_collection import RawPathCollection
File "/anaconda3/pkgs/vispy-0.4.0.106.gf8a69d0-np110py35_0/lib/python3.5/site-packages/vispy/visuals/collections/raw_path_collection.py", line 7, in <module>
  from vispy import glsl
File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/vispy/__init__.py", line 30, in <module>
  from .util import config, set_log_level, keys, sys_info  # noqa
File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/vispy/util/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
  from .logs import logger, set_log_level, use_log_level  # noqa
File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/vispy/util/logs.py", line 6, in <module>
  import logging
File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/logging/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
  import sys, os, time, io, traceback, warnings, weakref, collections
File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/traceback.py", line 5, in <module>
  import linecache
File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/linecache.py", line 11, in <module>
  import tokenize
File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/tokenize.py", line 98, in <module>
  class TokenInfo(collections.namedtuple('TokenInfo', 'type string start end line')):
AttributeError: module 'collections' has no attribute 'namedtuple'
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: do you maybe have a file named `collections.py` in your directory?

Comment: ^either that or a python module `collections` (a dir with `__init__.py` in it)

Comment: are you certain your python shell is python3?

Comment: I was located in directory that had a `collections` subdirectory. That was silly, but I'm learning. Thanks.